# Is it possible to set a button layout from FXML?

Tags: java, javafx

I just want to ask when I make a new button in JavaFX within an FXML scene, is it possible to load the layout of the button from a supplementary FXML file?

For instance, instead of manually creating a button like this:
(Note: Not supposed to be correct code, just an example)

```
Button a = new Button();
HBox b = new HBox();
a.getChildren().add(b);
a.setOpacity(0.5)
```

would it be possible to load it from a supplementary FXML file? A file that would contain all basic properties.. like size, position, contents, images, etc. Something like:

```
FXMLLoader b = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
Button a = b.loadElement(id_of_a_in_fxmlfile);
```

Is this a thing?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but for your purpose I would suggest to have a look at *Prototype Design Pattern* for creating your custom button, and cloning it with defined properties.

Answer (score 0):

Okay indeed this isn't a function currently available in JavaFX, HOWEVER..

It is possible using AOP (AspectJ) to define an extra method within FXMLLoader to allow this, but of course you'd have to analyze how FXMLLoader opens and loads FXML files and define the behavior yourself.

This is currently the only way.